# How to capture controller name when it actually not controller in nlog .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

NLog can capture the controller name and action using `{aspnet-mvc-controller}` and `{aspnet-mvc-action}` configuration options, it works fine.

In my case, there is an action that not using a controller pattern (tusdotnet). When I want to log activity on that action, the values in `{aspnet-mvc-controller}` and `{aspnet-mvc-action}` are empty.

Is there a way to manually set {aspnet-mvc-controller} and {aspnet-mvc-action}?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/5332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[${aspnet-mvc-controller}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-MVC-Controller-Layout-Renderer) and [${aspnet-mvc-action}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-MVC-Action-Layout-Renderer) extracts their values (`controller` + `action`) from `HttpContext.Current.GetRouteData`.

If there is no HttpContext, then you can consider implementing a fallback-value using `whenEmpty=`. Ex. Logging like this:

```cs
logger.WithProperty("MvcAction", "myAction")
      .WithProperty("MvcController", "myController")
      .Info("Hello World");
```

And then configure the layout like this:

- `${event-properties:MvcAction:whenEmpty=${aspnet-mvc-action}}`
- `${event-properties:MvcController:whenEmpty=${aspnet-mvc-controller}}`

Instead of using `${event-properties}` then you could also use [ScopeContext / BeginScope](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ScopeProperty-Layout-Renderer). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging